# Select one row of duplicated row with multiple columns as distinct

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there anyway in Oracle, it can select the first row of the rows with duplicated value in column val1 and val2?

```
ID  val1    val2
==================
1   1       1
2   1       1
3   2       2
4   2       3
5   2       3
6   3       2
7   3       2
8   2       2

Expect:
ID  val1    val2
==================
1   1       1
3   2       2
4   2       3
6   3       2
8   2       2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) to help you:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.val1, t.val2 FROM
    (SELECT ID, val1, val2, ROW_NUMBER()
       OVER (PARTITION BY val1, val2 ORDER BY ID) AS rownumber
       FROM table1) t
WHERE t.rownumber = 1
```

Here I use a subquery, where a get a row number for each record, partitioning the records by `val1` and `val2`. Then I use outer query to filter only row that have `rownumber=1`, which returns the values that you need.

**UPDATE:** I did not notice, that you can have the same repeating values in your expected result (e.g. IDs 3 and 8 should both be displayed in results), where my initial query would not include ID 8.

Here is alternative solution that gives results just like in your expected results:

```
SELECT 
    t.ID, 
    t.val1, 
    t.val2 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        val1, 
        val2, 
        LAG(val1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) as previousVal1, 
        LAG(val2) OVER (ORDER BY ID) as previousVal2
    FROM table1) t
WHERE 
    (t.previousVal1 IS NULL and t.previousVal2 IS NULL) OR 
    t.val1 <> t.previousVal1 OR 
    t.val2 <> t.previousVal2
ORDER BY t.ID
```

Here in subquery I used function [`LAG`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) to get previous values of `val1` and `val2`. Then in outer query I select a first record (specified by condition `t.previousVal1 IS NULL and t.previousVal2 IS NULL`) and all records where values of `val1` and `val2` are different from the previous record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pair of subselect

```
select ID, val1, val2 
from my_table 
where (id) in (select min(id) from my_table where (vali1, val2) in 
(select distinct val1,val2 from my_tbale))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_value(ID) over (PARTITION BY val1, val2 ORDER BY ID), val1, val2 FROM your_tbl
```

But it shurely will not give you row (8, 2, 2), because val1 and val2 are the same as in row (3, 2, 2).